# python: slicing string, taking value from substring start + n, and then using that value to calculate length of new substring

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to read the contents of a file, look for a specific string, and then read the following 2 characters (hex formatted integer) as `x`, then `substring` the following string of length `x`.

**Example:** If the contents of the file is as follows:

> 1390145993**ASDF**06452048091938HFDJGK3985719**ASDF**031395829382235235235235235235DHFGAJDGF**ASDF**103235923785907230646246246346734735746845698

1. Look for `ASDF`.
2. Read next 2 characters (06). So we need 6 hex values.
3. Read next 6 hex values `452048091938`.
4. So the required string is `ASDF06452048091938`.
5. Continue till the end of the file.

**The Desired Output will be:**

1. `ASDF06452048091938`
2. `ASDF03139582`
3. `ASDF103235923785907230646246246346734`

**So far I have tried:**

```
location=1

while True:

    location=file.find('ASDF', location+1)

if location==-1:

    break

print file[location:]
```

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. It was closed as *unclear what the poster was asking* which is not true. The question is clear. Those who vote did not read the question carefully.

Comment: Here is my solution since the question is closed: https://pastebin.com/kjq6anjs

Comment: Edited the question to avoid further confusion. I think now it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

slice out the length you want. Cast it to an int and then slice the substring.

```
location = 0

while True:
    location=file.find('ASDF', location+1)
    if location == -1:
        break
    length = int(file[location+4:location+6], 16)
    print file[location:location+6+length*2]
```

Output:

```
ASDF06452048091938
ASDF03139582
ASDF1032359237859072306462
```

Comment: Its hex, so `int(file[location+4:location+6], 16)`

Comment: ...and `location=0` in case the string starts with ASDF